# Multivariable Chain Rule Notation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative, chain-rule

(without using tree diagram)

If

> z = f(x − y)
>
> g(x, y) = x − y
>
> so that z =$f∘g$

use the chain rule to show that

> $\frac{∂z}{∂x}$+ $\frac{∂z}{∂y}$ = 0

**Answer:**
Why does the chain rule imply this answer?

> $\frac{∂z}{∂x}$ =$\frac{∂f}{∂g}$$\frac{∂g}{∂x}$ =$\frac{∂f}{∂g}$

and

> $\frac{∂z}{∂y}$=$\frac{∂f}{∂g}$$\frac{∂g}{∂y}$ =$-\frac{∂f}{∂g}$

Comment: You have show that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$. Your proof is correct. What is the problem?

Comment: I do not understand why the chain rule implies the answer given

Comment: @mathguy do you know how to apply the chain rule?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering about how the notation works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as ${\partial f\over\partial x}$ or ${\partial f\over\partial y}$. We are given that
$$z(x,y):=f\bigl(g(x,y)\bigr)\ ,$$
where $f$ is a *function of one variable*, hence has an ordinary derivative $f'$, and $g(x,y)=x-y$. The chain rule says that
$${\partial z\over\partial x}=f'\bigl(g(x,y)\bigr){\partial g\over\partial x}=f'\bigl(g(x,y)\bigr)\cdot1\ ,$$
and similarly
$${\partial z\over\partial y}=f'\bigl(g(x,y)\bigr){\partial g\over\partial y}=f'\bigl(g(x,y)\bigr)\cdot(-1)\ .$$
It follows that
$${\partial z\over\partial x}+{\partial z\over\partial y}\equiv0\ .$$

Comment: Well I just copied directly from the answer key

Answer (score 0):

**Using the chain rule** you have proved that:
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =-\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}
$$

so :
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}=0
$$

And this result is true **in general** (if the request derivatives exist) thanks to the chain rule.

Comment: My question is that I do not understand the proof using the chain rule